# Extract all values for a single key in a js array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a json collection of objects

```
{  
   "images":{  
      "1":{  
         "image_data":{  
            "votable":true,
            "hashed_filename":"d66f00cf58c4fbbbc9703efff9c7694c"
         },
         "image_reference":1
      },
      "2":{  
         "image_data":{  
            "votable":true,
            "hashed_filename":"5485a21d47e3815cd7f23d5f8a8c8677"
         },
         "image_reference":2
      },
      "3":{  
         "image_data":{  
            "votable":true,
            "hashed_filename":"4df10b887f12d65f2f541c99f0dd1ef8"
         },
         "image_reference":3
      }
   }
}
```

Is there an easy way to extract the hashed_filename value in a string separated by underscore?

I need a result like `d66f00cf58c4fbbbc9703efff9c7694c_5485a21d47e3815cd7f23d5f8a8c8677_4df10b887f12d65f2f541c99f0dd1ef8`

Comment: Sometimes, sharing why you’re trying to do something helps answerers give you a better answer.

Comment: I know, but is not easy in this situation...

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Get all values from the object as array, get `image_data.hashed_filename` from each object in the array, and then join all the values with `_`.

```
Object.values(obj.images).map(x => x.image_data.hashed_filename).join('_')
```

But there are no guarantees on the order of values while evaluating `Object.values(obj.images)` as objects are unordered in JS.

To order by the keys, get the keys from the object, sort the keys, get the value for each key. Then map over `image_data.hashed_filename` and join (same as before).

```
Object.keys(obj.images).sort().map(x => obj.images[x])
  .map(x => x.image_data.hashed_filename).join('_')
```

Comment: And If I want to keep the order?

Comment: @RobertoPezzali, just use object.keys method.

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai Thanks! Edited.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali Objects are unordered in JS.
Updated the answer with a solution to sort by keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. You could do something like this:

```js
var o = {  
   "images":{  
      "1":{  
         "image_data":{  
            "votable":true,
            "hashed_filename":"d66f00cf58c4fbbbc9703efff9c7694c"
         },
         "image_reference":1
      },
      "2":{  
         "image_data":{  
            "votable":true,
            "hashed_filename":"5485a21d47e3815cd7f23d5f8a8c8677"
         },
         "image_reference":2
      },
      "3":{  
         "image_data":{  
            "votable":true,
            "hashed_filename":"4df10b887f12d65f2f541c99f0dd1ef8"
         },
         "image_reference":3
      }
   }
};

var result = Object.keys(o.images).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc += (acc ? "_" : "") + o.images[key].image_data.hashed_filename; 
    return acc;
},"")

console.log(result);
```

Here, you can find out more about [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var result = "";
    var findByValue = function (o, key) {           
        var p;
        for (p in o) {                
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof o[p] === 'object') {                    
                if (o[p][key])
                {                                           
                    result += o[p][key] + "_";                        
                }
                findByValue(o[p], key);                                       
           }
        }       
    };
    findByValue(_data, "hashed_filename");
    console.log(result.substring(0, result.length -1));
```